# PHP Required field Error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a field required.. it posts the required error but it also posts the set_message the set_message should only display on success.

but it is posting both at the same time. What is happening is the required field is not stoping  the function from updating if its blank

```
<?php 
function recover_password(){

    $errors = [];


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['token']) {

            $email = clean($_POST['email']);

            if (empty($email)) {
   $errors[] = "Email Address Required";
}

if (! empty($errors)) {
   echo validation_errors($errors[0]);}



            if (email_exists($email)) { 

                $validation_code = generaterandom(12);

                setcookie('temp_access_code', $validation_code, time() + 86400);

                $sql = "UPDATE users SET validation_code = '" . escape($validation_code) . "' WHERE user_email = '" . escape($email) . "'";
                $result = query($sql);


                set_message("Instructions to reset your password have been emailed to you");        


            } else {

                echo validation_errors("This email does not exist");
            }
        } else {

            redirect("index.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the `else` that the parser is encountering?  Your first code snippet is very incomplete.

Comment: Are you using HTML5? If so, just add a `required` property to the input.

Comment: @JayBlanchard You still need to perform the check server-side because the client-side check can easily be bypassed. Use it as a nice enhancement on top of robust validation.

Comment: You're preaching to the choir @BobbyJack :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be ok.
Your if ... else  construct seems to be ok.
But the statement *$errors = [];* is not

```
<?php 
function recover_password(){
    $errors = array();
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['token']) {
            $email = clean($_POST['email']);
            if (email_exists($email)) { 
                $validation_code = generaterandom(12);
                setcookie('temp_access_code', $validation_code, time() + 86400);
                $sql = "UPDATE users SET validation_code = '" . escape($validation_code) . "' WHERE user_email = '" . escape($email) . "'";
                $result = query($sql);
                set_message("Instructions to reset your password have been emailed to you");        
            } else {
                echo validation_errors("This email does not exist");
            }
        } else {
            redirect("index.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That array initialisation syntax is fine in PHP 5.4+

Answer (score -1):

This worked perfectly I needed to add another else statement I have updated the code...

```
function recover_password()
{
    $errors = [];

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['token']) {

            $email = clean($_POST['email']);

            if (empty($email)) {

                $errors[] = "Email Address Required";
            }

            if (! empty($errors)) {

                echo validation_errors($errors[0]);
            } else {

                if (email_exists($email)) {

                    $validation_code = generaterandom(12);

                    setcookie('temp_access_code', $validation_code, time() + 86400);

                    $sql = "UPDATE users SET validation_code = '" . escape($validation_code) . "' WHERE user_email = '" . escape($email) . "'";
                    $result = query($sql);


                    set_message("Instructions to reset your password have been emailed to you");
                } else {

                    echo validation_errors("This email does not exist");
                }
            }
        } else {

            redirect("index.php");
        }
    }
}
```